# Problems with mirror+subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, mirror

I'm new to Blender and am trying to do the chair tutorial from Blender Guru. I created a plane, added the mirror modifier and resized it to half. Up to this point everything worked fine. Then I added the subdivision surface modifier and it created 2 circles. I tried to apply scale and rearange the modifiers but nothing worked.
[image]

Comment: The 'Merge' in your _Mirror_ modifier isn't catching. With the 3D Cursor at 0 (Shift-C), and the transform pivot-point set to it, select the vertices supposed to be on the mirror-axis, and SX0 scale them to the YZ plane. See if that helps.

Comment: Or just move the vertices towards the mirror axis, since _Clipping_ is enabled they shouldn't go beyond the axis.

Comment: Also you'll need to remove the face that is in the axis of the mirror

Comment: thank you for the answers. I tried the suggestions but in the end I increased the merge factor and that solved the problem.